# Check if Linked List is sorted (ascending order) or not in C?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, linked-list

```
struct node* acc_check(struct node *head) {

int count = 0, count2 = 0;
for (struct node *ptr = head; ptr->next != NULL; ptr = ptr->next) {
    count++;
    if (ptr->data <= ptr->next->data) {
        count2++;
    }
}
if (count == count2)
    printf("Ascending Order");
else
    printf("Not in Ascending Order");
return head;

}
```

I am always getting "Ascending Order", please help me to figure out the problem.
Here is the full source code, [LINKED LIST CODE](https://pastebin.com/L2u9cMNE)

Comment: When you found your program didn't work as desired what did you do next? Have you made any attempt to debug it yourself? If so, what did you find? And please provide the code in the question itself and not as an external link.

Comment: Do you have a sample list that is definitely not sorted? When you step through the code with that list as input, do `count` and `count2` both get incremented? If yes, under what conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look carefully to your code, you are sorting the elements of the list when creating the list:

```
    case 1: {
        head = create_11(head);
        head = sort_list(head);
    }
```

If you comment the sorting of the list you will obtain the expected result.

Comment: Ohh, Thanks I was missing this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Independent on whether the list is already sorted or not in any case the function is incorrect.

For starters it can have undefined behavior because the user can call the function for an empty list. In this case this expression

```
ptr->next != NULL
```

will invoke undefined behavior.

The function shall not output any message. It is the caller of the function will decide whether to output any message. What it shall do is to return integer value either 0 or 1 reporting whether the list is unsorted or sorted.

Moreover to make the conclusion that the list is not sorted there is no need to traverse it to its end. The variables `count` and `count2` do not make sense. They are redundant.

The function can be defined the following way.

```
int acc_check( const struct node *head ) 
{
    if ( head != NULL )
    {
        const struct node *prev = head;
        while ( ( head = head->next ) != NULL && !( head->data < prev->data ) )
        {
            prev = head;
        }
    }

    return head == NULL;
}
```